# Some clarification about this section of ant script?

Tags: java, ant

I am studying how **ant** work and I have some doubts related to it. I have an ant xml script definition file that begin in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Peacock Engine" default="default">       <!-- "default" is the default target -->

<tstamp />

<!-- ============================================ -->
<!-- Load build properties                        -->
<!-- ============================================ -->

<property name="project.buildfile" value="build.num" />

<property file="${project.buildfile}" />

<property file="info.properties" />

<!-- ============================================ -->
<!-- Specify the classpath                        -->
<!-- ============================================ -->

<path id="project.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${project.libdir}">
        <include name="${project.libs}" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<!-- ============================================ -->
<!-- The default target                           -->
<!-- ============================================ -->

<target name="default" depends="jar"/>
```

Now help me to analyze this:

1) **project** tag is the **root target** and I use it to specify the project attributes.

2) : what exactly do this line?

3) Then I have these lines:

```
<property name="project.buildfile" value="build.num" />
<property file="${project.buildfile}" />
<property file="info.properties" />
```

What exactly do? I think that the first line create something like a variable named **project.buildfile** and load into it the content of a file named **build.num**
REgarding the following 2 lines I have few idea about what they do...can you help me?

4) Then in the ant script I find these lines:

```
<!-- ============================================ -->
<!-- Specify the classpath                        -->
<!-- ============================================ -->

<path id="project.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${project.libdir}">
        <include name="${project.libs}" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

I tryed to search on the web but I have totaly no idea about this section

5) Finnslly I have this section that is the **definition of the default target** that is the default action that is executed when I launch the ant script withous specify a specific task (a specific target):

```
<!-- ============================================ -->
<!-- The default target                           -->
<!-- ============================================ -->

<target name="default" depends="jar"/>
```

I am not totally sure about it but I think that by this line I am sayng that the default behavior of the ant script is to compile the program and that the compiled program is put it inside a Jar file.

Someone can help me to understand better this script code?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) and 2) This sets the name of the project to "Peacock Engine" and sets the default task to the task named "default" (see 5)). The default task will be executed if you invoke Ant without providing a specific task:

```
<project name="Peacock Engine" default="default">
```

3) `<property name="project.buildfile" value="build.num" />` creates a property which you can access anywhere in your Ant file with `${project.buildfile}`. The value of the property will be `build.num`

`<property file="${project.buildfile}" />` makes use of the above defined property. It basically loads the file "build.num" and makes all properties that are defined in this file available for further use. How does a property file work ? [Have a look at the ant documentation of the property file task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html).

`<property file="info.properties" />` loads another property file called "info.properties" and also makes all the properties in this file available to Ant.

4)

```
<path id="project.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${project.libdir}">
        <include name="${project.libs}" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

This tag defines a classpath. The `path` tag encloses a fileset. The fileset includes all libraries in `${project.libdir}` that include the name `${project.libs}`. Both are variables that might have been defined by including the property files above.
Effectively this tag gives you a set of libraries that can be included anywhere in the build file by referencing it's id (`project.classpath`).

5) `<target name="default" depends="jar"/>` see 1). The project tag references this target as default target when no target is supplied. This target has another target which it depends on. The target named in "depends" will be executed before "default". Again, if "jar" has another target that it depends on, this target will be executed first, and so on. It is a "call-graph". See the [documentation on targets](http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html) for more information on this.

You may want to have a look at the Ant documentation for [writing a simple build file](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html) as a starting point to get more familiar with Ant.

Comment: 5) This means if you just run `ant`, it will execute the target `default`.  The only interesting thing about this target is that it depends on the `jar` target, so that will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) project tag is the root target and I use it to specify the project attributes.

The project tag simply names the project, you also have the default target defined. The project tag is not, itself, a target.

```
<property name="project.buildfile" value="build.num" />
```

Creates a property named `project.buildfile` and sets the value to 'build.num'

```
<property file="${project.buildfile}" />
```

reads a set of properties from a file, the name of which is stored in the property `project.buildfile`, the value of which, in this case, is 'build.num'.

```
<property file="info.properties" />
```

reads a set of properties from a file named 'info.properties'

```
<path id="project.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${project.libdir}">
        <include name="${project.libs}" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

Creates a `path` named 'project.classpath'. The path will have the root defined in the projectlib.dir property and contains all files defined in the project.libs property

```
<target name="default" depends="jar"/>
```

means that the target `default` is dependent on the target `jar` successfully completing first. Ant will run the `jar` target automatically to satisfy this requirement.

Apache maintains a [manual for Ant here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should go to [Ant Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) and read through it. It'll help you understand many of your questions.

#### Project Line

Ant files are XML files, and XML files have a *root* entity that encloses all the other entities. This is what the `<project>` entity is. Here's a simple Ant build.xml file:

```
<project>
    <echo message="Hello, World!"/>
</project>
```

The sole task in this file (`<echo>`) is enclosed in the `<project>` XML entity.

The `<project>` entity can take some attributes:

- **`name`**: The name of the Ant project. This is available in the `${ant.project.name}` property.
- **`default`**: The default *target* you want to execute. Ant basically has a two-level hierarchy. There are *targets* and there are *tasks*. A *target* is what you want to execute (compile, package, execute, clean, etc.), and *targets* contain tasks to accomplish what you want to do.
- **`basedir`**: The base directory used when you specify a directory. The default is the current directory.
- **`XML Namespaces`**: Don't worry about this one for now. You won't be using this until you get more comfortable with Ant.

#### Property Lines:

> Then I have these lines:

```
<property name="project.buildfile" value="build.num" />
<property file="${project.buildfile}" />
<property file="info.properties" />
```

Ant uses something called *properties* which you can think of as *variables*. However, once a property is set, it can't be changed. For example:

```
<property name="foo" value="This is the initial value of foo"/>
<property name="foo" value="This is my new value"/>
```

The first line sets `${foo}` to *This is the initial value of foo*. The second line does nothing. In fact, it doesn't *fail* or anything. It simply doesn't reset the value.

You can use this to adjust your build system by creating *property files* that Ant will read in first before the build takes place. The first line sets a property called `${project.buildfile}` to the file `build.num`. This is the build number. The second line reads in all the properties in this file and sets their values. The third line reads in another property file that may setup other properties. Here's a quick example:

```
<project>
    <property file="build.num"/>
    <property name="build.number" value="Not Set"/>
    <echo message="The build number is ${build.number}"/>
</project>
```

Let's say there's no file called `build.num`. In this case, `${build.number}` is set to `Not Set`, and the build file will print out:

```
The build number is Not Set
```

Now, let's make a file called `build.num`, and it is this:

```
build.number = 1234
```

Now, when I run the build, it will read in the property `build.number` from the `build.num` file. The `<property name="build.number" value="Not Set"/>` won't change the build number since it was already set. The build will now print out:

```
The build number is 1234
```

Now, let's say I run my build like this:

```
$ ant -Dbuild.number=9876
```

I am setting `${build.number}` on my command line. The build will still read in the file `build.num`, but won't set `${build.number}` from it since I've already set it. The line `<property name="build.number" value="Not Set"/>` will also be ignored since `${build.number}` is already set.

#### Path

> Then in the ant script I find these lines:

```
<!-- ============================================ -->
<!-- Specify the classpath                        -->
<!-- ============================================ -->

<path id="project.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${project.libdir}">
        <include name="${project.libs}" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

There are two types of data in Ant. One is the *properties* which I mentioned above. The other are *Paths*. A Path is a series of files or directories. You see this in Unix and Windows with the `PATH` environment variable:

```
$ echo $PATH
$ /bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/david/bin
```

If I type in a command, the operating system will search each of my directories in the PATH to find that command. In Java, you have the `CLASS_PATH` which are the jars you need to compile your project.

This is setting a *path* called `project.classpath`. It basically takes all of the jars that matches the `<fileset>` criteria and puts them in a *path* that can be used later, maybe for the compilation.

#### Targets:

```
<target name="default" depends="jar"/>
```

As I mentioned earlier, Ant has a two level hierarchy: Targets are the things you want to accomplish. Think of them as a program. A `compile` target is a *program* to compile your code. Targets contain *tasks* that need to be done to run the *target*.

Some tasks depend upon other tasks. For example, a target to test my code will be dependent upon the target to compile the code. I can't test my code without it first compiling:

```
<target name="test" depends="compile">
    ....
</target>
```

Some targets simply specify other targets. For example, I have a target called `all`. This runs the target to *clean* up my directory structure and get rid of any previously built files, compile my code, run tests, and then to package up my code:

```
<target name="all" depends="clean,compile,test,package"/>
```

The `all` target doesn't do anything itself. It's just a way to combine all of the other targets into one easy to use target. I run `all`, and everything I need to do a complete build is done.

In this case, the developer is defining a target called `default` that runs the `jar` target.  You can see in their `<project>` entity that the default target for this project is called `default`, so if I run Ant without specifying a target, it will run the `default` target.

This is a bit convoluted. The developer could have left this out, and simply set `default="jar"` in the `<project>` entity.

As I mentioned before, go to the [Ant Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual) and it will help you learn Ant. Plus, give you a reference you can use to learn more about these various tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Dude Maven is the new kid on the block. Try it and you won't need ANT. I have been using it for a month now and no more going back to ANT. There are a lot of tutorials online on how to used it with your projects. [Maven Website](http://maven.apache.org/)

Comment: Maven is new? LOL.  Gradle and SBT are far better IMO.  :)

Comment: I'll certainly try them. But got to admit Maven is new to me.